# Help with how to pickle a ufunc?

Tags: python, numpy, mpi, pickle

I'm attempting to broadcast a module to other python processes with MPI. Of course, a module itself isn't pickleable, but the `__dict__` is. Currently, I'm pickling the `__dict__` and making a new module in the receiving process. This worked perfectly with some simple, custom modules. However, when I try to do this with NumPy, there's one thing that I can't pickle easily: the `ufunc`.

I've read this thread that suggests pickling the `__name__` and `__module__` of the `ufunc`, but it seems they rely on having numpy fully built and present before they rebuild it. I need to avoid using the `import` statement all-together in the receiving process, so I'm curious if the `getattr(numpy,name)` statement mentioned would work with a module that doesn't have `ufunc`s included yet.

Also, I don't see a `__module__` attribute on the `ufunc` in the NumPy documentation:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html

Any help or suggestions, please?

EDIT: Sorry, forgot to include thread mentioned above. http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2007-January/025778.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pickling a function in Python only serializes its name and the module it comes from. It does not transport code over the wire, so when unpickling you need to have the same libraries available as when pickling. On unpickling, Python simply imports the module in question, and grabs the items via `getattr`. (This is not limited to Numpy, but applies to pickling in general.)

Ufuncs don't pickle cleanly, which is a wart. Your options mainly are then to pickle just the `__name__` (and maybe the `__class__`) of the ufunc, and reconstruct them later on manually. (They are not actually Python functions, and do not have a `__module__` attribute.)

Comment: The receiving processes don't actually import anything because I just pickle the `__dict__` of a module through the `bcast` function in MPI (`mpi4py`). And then I make a blank module that I insert the `__dict__` into. I'll run it with my debug interpreter to see if it's actually importing anything like you're suggesting. The purpose of what I'm trying to do is to try and prevent the receiving processes from having to access the file system while still importing the module.

Comment: The imports happen inside `pickle.load`, which mpi4py calls -- this you don't have control over. (If you're interested, you can check out how pickling works: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/pickle.py#l1067 or just check hte pickle stream)  If you want to pass code over the wire bypassing the file system, that is possible (but perhaps you should file a separate question for that here) -- either just pass the Python code as in string and compile it with `exec` on the other side, or compile it to a code object and pass that over. However, you can't copy Numpy over like this.